# Optimized way to parse JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Tom",
        "Email": "tom@gmail.com",
        "Notes": "Yea, it's good",
        "Ratings": "5",
        "Messages": [
            "Tom - I am good",
            "System - How're you doing?",
            "Tom - True, that!",
            "System - Oh Yes! ;) "
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sunny",
        "Email": "sunny@gmail.com",
        "Notes": "Yea, it's good",
        "Ratings": "2",
        "Messages": [
            "Sunny-I am good",
            "System - How're you doing?",
            "Sunny - True, that!",
            "System - Oh Yes! ;) "
        ]
    }
]
```

I am parsing it using jQuery and iterating it like this;

```
            var jsonData = $("#jsonData").val();
            var plainData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);

            for (var j = 0; j < plainData.length; j++) {
                var Name = plainData[j].Name;
                var Email = plainData[j].Email;
                var Notes = plainData[j].Notes;
                var Ratings = plainData[j].Ratings;

                var Messages = plainData[j].Messages;
                var _messages = " ";
                for (var i = 0; i < Messages.length; i++)
                    _messages += Messages[i] + "\n";

            }
```

I'm not too sure if iterating this in a for loop is a good idea. Could anyone please suggest me a better/optimized way to iterate the parsed json value?

Comment: You're parsing the data just fine.  The question is what do you want *to do* with the data? The code sample makes it clear you're iterating, but gives no real information as to your use case.  Without that information it's hard to know what might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing it just now is the most efficient way to do it, except:

```
var Messages = plainData[j].Messages;
var _messages = " ";
for (var i = 0; i < Messages.length; i++)
    _messages += Messages[i] + "\n";
```

Could also be written better as :

```
_messages = plainData[j].Messages.join('\n') + '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

In older browsers (and some not so old) a negative while loop will be faster than a for loop if it can be used:

instead of

```
for (var j = 0; j < plainData.length; j++) {
```

use

```
var j=plainData.length;
while(j--) {
```

There used to be a blog with a reference of some quantitative metrics, but that page is dead, however the results could be reproduced fairly easily.

Speculation on why is that the comparison is on equality to zero rather than greater or less than comparisons and also that the Javascript, as an interpreted language could in-line the code to optimize with a known termis point but I don't have quantitative knowlege on this statement.

After a bit of wandering around the web room I found some quantification:

https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a