# IE stop running script error while converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

[image]

I am getting the above error in IE8 when I am trying to do **ko.toJSON()**

```
var data =  ko.toJSON(this),
```

I am trying to convert a huge model(this). It is working fine if there is less data in object.
But most of the time i will have huge data. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Here is good discussion on this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460263/disabling-the-long-running-script-message-in-internet-explorer). Basically, I think that if you want to mute this error, you'll have to either make your object smaller or perform JSON stringify yourself (divide object in smaller completed chunks of data, stringify each chunk and then concatenate them together).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimized way to parse JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480853/optimized-way-to-parse-json-data)